# Matlab crash on linux

Tags: matlab, crash

I started the Curve Fitting Toolbox and my MATLAB crashed. Here's what appears in the Linux console:

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5.a, but found libiomp5.so already initialized.
>
> OMP: Hint: This may cause performance degradation and correctness issues. Set environment variable `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE` to ignore this problem and force the program to continue anyway. Please note that the use of KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK is unsupported and using it may cause undefined behaviour. For more information, please contact Intel(R) Premier Support.
>
> Killed

I tried the `KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE` to no avail. I know this is a conflict between a static and dynamic library. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about the problem you've encountered, but setting environment variable inside of Matlab is done via [`setenv` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html):

```
setenv('KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK', 'TRUE');
```

Comment: Check from Matlab what this returns: `getenv('KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK')`. If it's `'TRUE'`, you've done it the right way - and my answer is superfluous.